# List callable font names for /etc/vconsole.conf

Tags: arch-linux, tty, plasma5, kde5

Using arch-linux with KDE plasma.

I would like to set my tty font to the ttf-hack font.

I added `FONT=ttf-hack` to `/etc/vconsol.conf`

And got no results. 
Actually I do not know what the right names for font and font_map are.
Is there a command to list both?
Is it possible at all, to use ttf fonts as tty output when not running a display server?

Comment: Do you have this font in your /usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts/ directory?  If you do, reboot your machine, the file is initiated on boot.

Comment: In fact I have no /usr/lib/kbd/ but kbd is located in /usr/share/kbd/ /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts does not have the font I want (Hack). 
These are in /usr/share/fonts/TTF 
Should I just copy them into the /kbd/consolefonts directory and add the font name to /etc/vconsol.conf ?
How can I know what the correct font name is, which I would pass in vconsol.conf ?
Would the name include the specifier "-Regular" and the ending .ttf?
I tried some combinations, not success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List the compatible terminal fonts (for TTY) with the command:

```
ls -l /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/ | grep -i ".psfu.gz"
```

See the ArchLinux [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console#Fonts).

---

Additionally, to list **all** available fonts (including incompatible ones), you can do:

```
fc-list
```

And search for a font with:

```
fc-list | grep -i "font name"
```